# How to change subsection to section and subsubsection to subsection?

Tags: sectioning, standalone

I remember learning how to to this long time ago, but I can't figure now how.

And google search is not turning anything.

I have a standalone latex file which starts with `subsection` because  this file is part of a larger document which will be all bundled using the standalone package into one large document.

But when I build this specific file on its own, I want the `subsection` to become `section` and the `subsubsection` to become `subsection`. This is what I tried

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{standalone}
\standalonetrue 

\ifstandalone %building this as standalone?
   \renewcommand{\subsection}{\section}
   \renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\subsection} 
\fi 

\begin{document}

\subsection{Problem 1} %this should become \section when standalone
\subsubsection{Part a} %this should become \subsection when standalone
A
\subsubsection{Part b}
B     
\end{document}
```

But when I compile the above using `lualatex` then both the `subsection` and the `subsubsection` become `section`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried

```
\ifstandalone 
\let\subsection\section
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\fi
```

same result.

What is the correct way to do this? The fix must only be in the preamble as shown above, nothing after the `\begin{document}`

Using TL 2018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\renewcommand` shouldn't work because it expands to whatever those are at the time you end up using them (ie, when you use the commands in your document, everything gets redefined to section).  `\let` changes the left to become whatever the right is at that moment.  With

```
\let\subsection\section
\let\subsubsection\subsection
```

`\subsection` becomes `\section`, and then `\subsubsection` becomes `\subsection` (which you just made `\section`).  It should work to reverse the `\let`s:

```
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
```

Then `\subsubsection` gets the same definition as `\subsection`, and `\subsection` gets the same definition as `\section`.

But why not just

```
\ifstandalone
\section{dummy section title}
\fi
```

instead of redefinitions?

Comment: Thanks. I remember now. It was the order trick. I've done this before as I said, but forgot how :) . As for why not the second way you show, it is because having it redefined in preamble means I do not need to add the code everywhere again in the document around each subsection, etc...in preamble, it is done once only.